# error 2006 MySQL Server has gone away with a 8GB file

Tags: mysql

First of all I already checked this question in previous posts, the answers given there didn't work for me, that's why I'm trying to get a functional answer with this post.

I'm trying to import a 8GB backup file into mySQL using:

```
mysql.exe -u root -p -h localhost dev8 < C:\dev8.sql
```

After 20 minutes processing it says:

**ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 8465: MySQL server has gone away**

And yes, I changed the max_allowed_packet using a very very large number in /bin/my, it didn't work so I changed it also in my-huge, my-innodb-heavy-4G, my-large, my-medium.

I also changed the phpmyadmin config file setting it to the same value. It didn't work either.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Break the file into smaller chunks?  Is the error always at line 8465?  How many lines in the file?

Comment: "MySQL server has gone away" typically means you exceeded the connection timeout, in my experience.

Comment: @AllInOne I tried to break it before, it didn't work, and yes, the error is always at line 8465 which is an empty line after a comment and before LOCK TABLES 'catalogsearch_result' WRITE.
The file has more than 20000 lines.

Comment: What do you mean breaking "didn't work"?  If you break it somewhere before line 8465 does the operation complete or do you get an error?

Comment: What is the value for MySQL wait_timeout? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: @AllInOne At first I broke it into multiple files because I was attempting to do it with phpmyadmin, but it gave me an error regarding a foreign key, to be honest I don't know what it was occurring. I'm trying to restore a database from a file that was given to me, I have nothing to do with the original file. innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
I just notice that innodb_lock_wait_timeout is commented and there's no other wait_timeout under my

Comment: My mistake, that line is not commented

Comment: what do you see when you query: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_%';

Comment: make sure you restarted mysql after changing variable values

Comment: @AllInOne that query gives me: wait_timeout = 28800

Comment: @FathahRehmanP after changing variable values I always restarted both apache and mysql

Comment: Some tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481716/how-to-prevent-connection-timeouts-for-large-mysql-imports maybe try big dump method?

Comment: @AllInOne I increased the wait_timeout to 90000 as well as the max_allowed_packet to 1040576. I restarted everything and now apparently it's working. I mean, more than an hour has passed and it hasn't thrown me any error. How can say if it got stuck or is still running? If I were using Linux I could use pv to display the execution percentage but since windows hasn't have that feature I don't know what to do. I'll wait a little longer. Anyway, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to install MySQL workbench. http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/  There are a number of management views screens that would be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exorbitant values for max_allowed_packet and wait_timeout. I mean, usually you should use a value that is 2 times the size of your import file, so if your import file is 8GB your max_allowed_packet should be at lease 16GB. Also increase to a really high number your wait_time_out.

A personal recommendation: Change these values directly in the tables, I mean, log in as a root into mysql and make the changes. I had the same problem before and just changing the text files was not enough, for me it didn't work until I changed the values in the db.