# MySql Is There a Limit on the size of a query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore a MySql database I had from version 3 of MySql from backups I saved.  I have installed version 5.6.17.  When I try to create a table from a file that is 60+ lines long it fails with ERROR 1064 in line 22.  If I delete line 22 it complains about the new line 22.

I trust the SQL file I am using because I got it from a backup of the old MySql.

Is ther a limit that can be increased to allow this table create to work?

Comment: Have you googled the error 1064? You can increase mysql execution time limit in the php.ini file.

Comment: Show this offending line and the **exact** error message. 1064 is the syntax error and IMHO has nothing to do with the length of your sql script

Comment: Might be [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481716/how-to-prevent-connection-timeouts-for-large-mysql-imports/17481838#17481838).

Answer (score 2):

You will see the 1064 MySQL syntax error when you incorrectly use reserved words such as `when` or `order`. These reserved words may differ for each version of MySQL. Considering you are trying to restore a db from version 3 it is likely you are getting the 1064 error due to MySQL version mismatch. You should check the version 3 sql file for conflicting reserved words that may be causing the 1064 syntax error.

Please see [MySQL Reserved Words 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) for more information on reserved words.