# mySQL script time out

Tags: mysql, timeout

I have a PHP file that create 20 database from a zip file. The file are from 100 record to 100 000 record. Now when i do each table INDIVIDUALLY, everything is fine. When i do it all at once... the server timeout and stop doing table in the process...

question, how do i increase the time for the server to make all table, but i dont know how much it need because it never finish.... or what can i do to relax the load on the server ?

i have no idea where to start to find a solution... and i dont like to make 20 cron that execute the database building, that just not make sense...

Comment: error code : The connection has timed out
The server at xxx.yy is taking too long to respond.

Comment: try running them in separate thread

Comment: @Doan Cuong, and how i do that in php ?

Comment: I'm not quite good at PHP to give you a proper answer, but you can refer to [PHP multi-threading document](http://www.php.net//manual/en/intro.pthreads.php) to learn more about it. Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change some setting in your php.ini :

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M 
;or whatever size you want

max_execution_time = 60
; also, higher if you must
```

Chances are if your reading this, PHPMyAdmin was not an option for your large MySQL database import. Nonetheless it is always worth a try right? Most common causes of failure for PHPMyAdmin imports is exceeding the import limit. If your working locally or have your own server, you can try changing the MySQL ini settings usually found in the my.ini file located in the MySQL install folder. If your working with WAMP on Windows, you can access that file using the WAMP control panel under MySQL > my.ini. Remember to restart WAMP so your new settings will be used. Settings you may want to increase here include:

```
max_allowed_packet
read_buffer_size
```

Even with enhanced MySQL import settings you may still find that imports time out due to PHP settings. If you have access to PHP.ini, you can make edits to the maximum execution time and related settings. In WAMP access the PHP.ini file under the WAMP control panel at PHP > php.ini. Consider raising the limits on the following settings while trying large MySQL imports:

```
max_execution_time
max_input_time
memory_limit
```

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481716/how-to-prevent-connection-timeouts-for-large-mysql-imports)

Comment: max_execution_time = 1200 and upload_max_filesize = 1000M... and it's still crash !

Comment: I had this problem too, but there are some DBMS for mysql like mysql-workbench but you cant use them on server, see this documentation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481716/how-to-prevent-connection-timeouts-for-large-mysql-imports

Comment: what value did you suggest for the following ? : max_allowed_packet
read_buffer_size

Comment: The protocol limit for max_allowed_packet is 1GB. The value should be a multiple of 1024; nonmultiples are rounded down to the nearest multiple. and read_buffer_size is a SSV (server system variable) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: @menardmam is this answer usefull?

Comment: Still timing out, with all the variable suggested increase... it time out after 5 minute more or less...still looking for a solution in the trace file...

Comment: @menardmam Oh, Pleaese see http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server

Comment: @menardmam plase wait a minute I will give you the best answer!

Comment: Maybe, i just get this idea.... i am doing a new(PDO) for each table... maybe this is taking too much ressources ?