# What is limiting the number of SQL statements PHP executes before timing out?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a large number of records into my table using SQL statements written like this:

```
INSERT INTO itemlist(UPC_Case,Pack,Size,Description,Weight_Case,UPC_Retail,TI,HI,MCL,CM,GSC,FL,HAN) VALUES (<values>);
```

a long series of these is in a textfile named `itemlist insert.sql`

I decided to use phpmyadmin to import these but the whole file wouldn't upload so I split it and compressed the pieces and when I ran the import it ran for a few minutes before only got through ~3850 record (~850,000 positions) before timing out and this definitely struck me as taking too long to do too little 3850 records seems like a very small amount of data to be processed in about 5 minutes (I mean that must be what, >1MB?), , so I thought that the php settings relating to script execution must be set too low for this kind of import, so I followed [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04) and changed the settings they mentioned:

In `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`:

```
post_max_size = 30M (was 8M)
upload_max_filesize = 30M (was 2M)
memory_limit = 1G (was 128M)
max_execution_time = 60 (was 30)
max_input_time = 120 (was 60)
```

Then I restarted apache: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

I know the settings have been applied because the max filesize did change and that meant I wouldn't have to compress my files, which I thought, combined with the other changes, would help the SQL statements not only be processed quicker, but also that it would have twice as much time before running out; meaning at least twice as many would get processed before the script times out, right?

But there was no improvement at all. phpmyadmin still only gets through ~3850 record (~850,000 positions) before timing out.

Why was there no improvement, what is limiting the number of statements that get processed because it wasn't any of those PHP settings. Does phpmyadmin have some sort of hidden limit?

Comment: It must be another thing, maybe related to MySQL, because you had an maximum execution time of 30 seconds (now 60) but you say that the script runs for 5 minutes before timing out, so it seems PHPMyAdmin is working around that limit in some way. Also, I 'm not sure what you mean by 'positions', but inserting 850.000 rows in five minutes is not a bad number.

Comment: I don't know what it means by position either but that's what it says every time the script stops. I assume it is close to equivalent to meaning 'character'. Which means that no, it's not 850,000 rows, it's less than 4,000

Comment: In that case, yes, 5 minutes is a lot for 4000 rows in a table with a dozen of fields, IMO this points to a problem in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin is not a tool, designed for importing big files into Mysql.

**Try using [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) command line tool.**

In case of Unix/Mac:

```
mysql -u {username} -p{password} {database_name} < import_file.sql
```

For all OS:

```
mysql -u {username} -p{password} -e "\. import_file.sql" {database_name}
```

Regarding **possible reasons of slow import**, it's ussually: table already has many records, unique indexes on this table, triggers, slow server, slow connection.

Comment: I'm trying the commandline right now, I'll let you know how long it takes or if it times out. As for the possible reasons (in original order): table was empty; only one unique `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID field; not sure what you mean by "triggers"; server is slow but certainly not enough to account for this; there is no connection, this is being run on localhost.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because, although it doesn't seem to go faster, I didnt have to resume it over and over again, all the queries ran from start to finish without interruption.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth noting, though I don't know that this is your problem, that MySQL also has a timeout setting.

 If you exceed the MySQL timeout then your queries will also fail.

 Here's a [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17481838/1748266) that should explain what you need in timeouts.


 Since you have command line access and, if the exported data is in a SQL format, you can import at command line. This approach may sidestep the problems you're experiencing, (basically you [run the exported data as a script](https://www.google.com/search?q=importing%20a%20mysql%20dump%20at%20command%20line&oq=importing%20a%20mysql%20dump%20at%20command%20line&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.12035j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=high)).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I did try running it through the CLI and although it doesn't seem to run any faster, it did execute all the statements without timing out.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that I edited the wrong php.ini (`/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`) for using the CLI, the correct one would have been `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`

Comment: @MarkKramer glad it worked, that's generally the approach I've taken with importing. Interesting that exporting seems so flawless.
I've also taken the SQL from a dump file and copied that into the SQL box in PHPMyAdmin and had it work... but I don't think I've ever done this when the database had a lot of data.

Comment: WOW, I just had to redo this table and I found out why it was taking so long. It was just because I had one insert statement per record. When I had to redo the same thing I had every record in a single insert statement and it only took a few minutes. Before it had to run all day long.

Comment: @MarkKramer That's definitely valuable information.