# Import mysql database to RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

It took already 12 hours, I try to import a sql file to RDS, I use this command :

```
mysqldump -u <user> -h <rds_server> -p <database> < filename.sql
```

But nothing works and as result, I have this error

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (i686)
--
-- Host: xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com    Database: xxxxxxxxxx
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.39-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT DISTINCT TABLESPACE_NAME, FILE_NAME, LOGFILE_GROUP_NAME, EXTENT_SIZE, INITIAL_SIZE, ENGINE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES WHERE FILE_TYPE = 'DATAFILE' AND TABLESPACE_NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('informagenie')) ORDER BY TABLESPACE_NAME, LOGFILE_GROUP_NAME': Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)
```

I'm waiting for your help !

**Edit 19/05/2018**

```
head -n 10 import_file.sql
```

done

```
-- Database Manager 4.2.5 dump

SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_2_wpmm_subscribers`;
CREATE TABLE `wp_2_wpmm_subscribers` (
  `id_subscriber` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Comment: You are using `mysqldump` incorrectly.  That tool is used on the *source* server, to create the backup.  For the destination -- which is what you seem to be doing -- the command is `mysql`, not `mysqldump`.  If you are loading a 5.7 dump onto RDS 5.6, that is also potentially going to be problematic.

Comment: OK, I correct my command but have the same result.

Mysql source is 5.5 version and destination is 5.6...

Did you have any solution ?

Comment: It isn't possible that you would get the same result.

Comment: Even if I use AWS DMS ?

Comment: The error you show came from mysqldump.  You may have a *similar* error using the `mysql` command, but it could not be identical.  Please use `mysql -u <user> -h <rds_server> -p <database> < filename.sql` and report the error you receive.

Comment: With mysql, I have this error instead : `ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 9: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: @Goms - what are the first few lines of the file?  We need to see lines 8,9,10.  Please edit the question to reflect the new command and error.

Comment: Do you have a huge number of tables / partitions?  How far apart are the client and server (ping time)?

Comment: @Goms, I hope you are doing this from a EC2 instance which in same AZ as your RDS instance. Also I would follow some of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481716/how-to-prevent-connection-timeouts-for-large-mysql-imports

Comment: @RickJames I updated question. Also, the file to import weighs 30Mo, if it is necessary to know !

Comment: @Goms - 30 Months?  30 MB?  30M rows?

Comment: 30 MB of size, the file by which I want import, 72 tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you are doing something fundamentally wrong in your command, or you are not able to even connect to RDS at all, that's why your import is not working. I'm here by stating the steps that will also help you in debugging the problem related to `connection failure` or `no connection at all`.

1. Try importing a simple file that I'm providing below. Its optional step, but I would recommend you do it.

Save below sql statements to file with name as **red_boy.sql**

```
Create database test_red;

use test_red;

CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
 id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50)
);

 INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('Red', 'Boy', 'red@example.com'),('Red1', 'Boy', 'red1@example.com'),('Red2', 'Boy', 'red3@example.com'),('Red4', 'Boy', 'red4@example.com');
```

2. Execute following command.

   ```
   mysql -u <username> -p<password> -h <rds-name.aws-region.rds.amazonaws.com> < red_boy.sql


   /**Replace <username> <password> and <rds-name.aws-region.rds.amazonaws.com> with full RDS URL.
   ```
3. If above two steps executed successfully, then there are no issue with your connection/permission with RDS, you are good to proceed further.

   ```
   mysql -u <username> -p<password> -h <rds-name.aws-region.rds.amazonaws.com> < filename.sql
   ```

All the above steps are fully verified on my RDS except step 3, and it works. Hence if doesn't work for you, then next step is to look into your files 'filename.sql' to see what is wrong in it. I could try re-attempt the answer.

**EDIT on 24/05/2018**
Based on @Doms comment, that step 3 is still failing, I see problem with one or multiple tables or over connection failure as size of data may be huge.

> Save following in one of sh files and execute it. It will do one by one table export from source database and import it into target database.

```
mysql -h source-database -u source_user -pSource_user_Password source_database --skip-column-names --execute='SHOW TABLES;' > tables.tmp
echo "Start!"
 while read p; do
  echo "Exporting" $p
  mysqldump -h source-database -u source_user -pSource_user_Password source_database $p > $p.sql
  echo "Importing" $p
  mysql -h target-database -u Target_db_user -pTarget_db_password target_db_name < $p.sql
  rm $p.sql
 done <tables.tmp

 rm tables.tmp
```

Comment: @Goms, did you try the steps, I have mentioned? If you're still facing challenges, I could try solving it.

Comment: both two steps above was successfully executed, after executing, I have one more database called `test_red` ! But with the third it didn't! Anything to add ?

Comment: @Goms, Issue is with the filename.sql only. One thing I suggest if you could re-export your database from source system?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. As on my source server, Provider had have possibility to migrate from mysql 5.5 to mysql 5.6... it is what I did and then, the import with `mysql -u <user> -h <rds_server> -p <database> < filename.sql` was successfully executed ! Thank you a lot for your support.