# Import a .sql file from localhost to remote awd rds

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a mysql .sql file on my desktop and a mysql database setup on a remote aws rds server.

Now I want to import the sql file i have on my desktop into the aws rds database but i am not sure how to do it. Was trying to use mysql workbench but that seems not to be able to use a local file as a source.

SO my next option is i was going to use terminal (I am a mac user) but not sure what the command would be to connect to the aws rds.

I have tried the below in terminal

mysql -h  -u root -P 3306 -p

however that gives a command not found message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql client on ec2 instance from where you connect to rds.

Then refer detailed steps here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50442954/1073487