# MySql Workbench Loses Connection with Long Running Query

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysql-error-2013

I'm trying to import a large file (105 million rows, 5 columns) into mySQL using Load Data Infile and I keep getting Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL Server.

My question is two parts:

1. How long is reasonable to extend the timeout so this doesn't happen?
2. Will the Query Keep running even if MySQL Workbench isn't responding?

Comment: i use the table data imprt wizard or the command prompt. This worked fine even with bid databases

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17481838/5193536 there is everything explaned