# ERROR 2013 (HY000) Lost connection to MySQL server during query - with Maria DB

Tags: import, backup, centos7, mariadb-10.3, mysql-error-2013

I saw [How to Prevent Connection Timeouts for Large MySQL Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481716/how-to-prevent-connection-timeouts-for-large-mysql-imports) but it didn't help.
I have checked the parameters of server.cnf in /etc/my.cnf.d/

```
 max_allowed_packet = 32M
 key_buffer_size = 3G
 innodb_buffer_size = 15G
 thread_cache_size = 50
 thread_stack = 192K
```

The DB is 250 Gb.
The disk space is ok.
I try a full import with the following command as root after drop database schema and create empty one :

```
sh -c 'nohup mysql -uroot -p*** --default-character-set=utf8 myschema < mysqlschemafullbackup.sql &'
```

MariaDB version : 10.3.39 on centOS 7.9
Can you help me solving this?

Kind regards,

I tried to launch the command 3 times and it stopped at various Gb size of the DB 19 Gb then 39 Gb.